# С большой ли буквы?

Tags: орфография

> Украинская санкционная продукция с территории Украины попадала в Крым
>   на краснодарских автобусах.

С большой ли буквы *краснодарские*? Как направление, а не как происхождение автобусов.

Comment: Опасаетесь разночтения — пишите «автобусах из Краснодара».

Comment: "Автобусы из Краснодара" - все равно не устраняет разночтения. Подходит как для автобусов, следующих из Краснодара, так и для автобусов, произведенных в Краснодаре.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно со строчной буквы. В русском языке прилагательные, образованные от географических названий пишутся со строчной буквы. Прописная буква пишется в том случае, если они являются составным наименованием.

Ср.:  невские берега, но: Невский проспект ( составное наименование).

Comment: Хочу подчеркнуть, что нужно ставить строчную букву в обоих случаях, упомянутых в вопросе (как направление и как происхождение)

Comment: Конечно, вы правы!